# Jquery to set all controls in a div to readonly - telerik controls arent readonly

Tags: jquery, html, telerik, telerik-mvc

Trying to default all controls in a  to readonly but the Telerik ones appear to not want to turn to readonly.

Example HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Entity.IssueDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Entity.IssueDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                            
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">
        Product
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Entity.ProductId)
                      .DataTextField("Text")
                      .DataValueField("Value")
                      .Filter("contains")
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" })
                      .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.Products, "Id", "FullName", Model.Entity.ProductId)))
    </div>
</div>
```

and the piece of code

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        if ($("#EventCommand").val() == "detail") {

            $(".form-control").prop("readonly", true);
        }

    });

</script>
```

Inserting the following line appears to work but I want something that is generic enough to handle all controls that are within a div tag (all have the form-control tag).

```
$("#Entity_ProductId").data("kendoDropDownList").readonly(true);
```

Any idea why the Telerik mvc kendo components don't seem to want to honor the readonly attribute in the same way as the normal html controls.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the HtmlAttribute on the component?

`.HtmlAttributes(new { @readonly = "readonly" })`

I tested it and it works just fine